# Xamarin.Android how to intercept activity closing / existing event before OnActivityResult is called

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, onactivityresult

I'm using Xamarin.Android. I have an activity say `activity_main` that has a button which brings up a new activity say `activity_list` that shows a list which users can reorder/remove items from.

When the user is done editing the list, **Back** button is pressed from `activity_list`, at which time I want to gather information of the modified list and pass an Intent with data back to `activity_main`.

I tried to override OnDestroy or OnStop method and call `SetResult` from there. But the `OnActivityResult` of activity_main is always executed before `SetResult`.

I know I can put a Finish button in activity_list by which I can gather my data and use Finish() to close activity_list. Also I can override OnBackPress() method to handle the **Back** button. But is there a way to have a callback/override method to handle the "activity closing" event like the Form_Closing event in WinForm apps, where I can execute all the operations before `OnActivityResult` is called, without invoking these operation from each and every exit triggers?

Answer (score -1):

Yes,since you  use `StartActivityForResult` from  page `activity_main`, then the `OnActivityResult` of `activity_main` will always been executed when you come back from `activity_list`.

According to your description,you can use the `resultCode` to judge whether you called the function `SetResult` or not. If you call `SetResult` with parameter `Result.Ok`,then we can pass value to page `activity_main`,if not the value `Result.Ok`, that's the other conditions.

Besides, you can also define a valarible `haveGetData` to identify if you need to pass data to `activity_main`.

For example:

in page `activity_main`

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0x001 ) {
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                string result = data.GetStringExtra("test");
                Log.Debug("123456", "******result = " + result);
            }
            else {
                Log.Debug("123456", "******cancel = null ");
            }
        }
    }
```

in page `activity_list`

```
//here define a bool value to flag if you need to pass data to page `activity_main`
 bool haveGetData = false;

 public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        //base.OnBackPressed();
        haveGetData = true;
        if (haveGetData)
        {
            var intent = new Intent();
            intent.PutExtra("test", "nicole..123");
            SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
            Finish();
        }
        else {
            var intent = new Intent();
            SetResult(Result.Canceled, intent);
            Finish();
        }
    }
```

**Update:**

Yes, you can use many ways to achieve this.One simple method is to use callBack.
For example, you can define a `EventHandler` in `activity_list`(I just define a simple string as parameter)

```
public static EventHandler<string> mEventHandler; // define a EventHandler
```

When current page is invisible when you come back to page `activity_main` , you can call it in method `OnStop()`:

```
protected override void OnStop()
    {
        base.OnStop();

        EventHandler<string> handler = mEventHandler;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            mEventHandler(this, "1111111");
        }
    }
```

Meanwhile, init it in  page `activity_main`:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
         // other code 
         // ActivityList  is the name of page `activity_list`
        ActivityList listActivity = new ActivityList();
        ActivityList .mEventHandler += delegate (object s, string a)
        {
            BackCall(s, a);
        };
    }
```

callback method `BackCall`

```
  void BackCall(object send, string s)
    {
        if (s == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(s));
        }

        Toast.MakeText(this, "call bakc value is: " + s, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you code. I cound't for the love of God get VS to prompt me OnBackPressed to override this morning. Now I found out that was because I used `protected` modifier while I should use `public`. Feeling silly now. BTW, is OnBackPressed the only way to execute code before caller activity's `OnActivityResult`? In case the exit is caused by somethings other than the **back** button, is there a more general OnExit or the sort I can use?

Comment: Also I might have not made it clear that my concern was about OnActivityResult of the `activity_main` being executed **before** `OnStop` or `OnDestroy` of `activity_list` , from which I hope to invoke `SetResult`.

Comment: In our previous development experience, when we go back to the previous page, we usually do it in two places, one is `OnBackPressed()` and another is the back button of  the toolbar.

Comment: So then there's 2 triggers, i.e. the back press and the toolbar button. Do you invoke SetResult on both trigger? I just don't like repeated code, be it only one line ;) In classic Windows Form application there's a Form_Closing event that guarantees to be invoked while closing, definitely before returning to parent form where all operations can be centralized. Is there an Android equivelent of this?

Comment: Then wen can try to call the same operations in both the two triggers.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm trying to avoid. Say if I decide to have more exiting triggers I'll have to add code to them over and over again. I want a centralized call back method that gets executed while activity is closing, exactly like Form_Closing event in WinForm apps. Call me OCD maybe...

Comment: You can just wrap the operations  in one model(e.g. a funcion), then just call it in the two places.

Comment: I just don't like repeated code, be it only one line, meaning call that function from more than one place. Let me rephrase my question.

Comment: Yes, in this question, the `OnActivityResult` of the `activity_main` is executed before `OnStop` or `OnDestroy` of activity_list, because the method `SetResult` is called before we call method `Finish();`.

Comment: Normally, we can deal with all operations in function `OnDestroy()` while we close a page, just as you say the same thing in `Form_Closing `event in WinForm apps.

Comment: Normally, yes. But in case of the need to set an result in the Intent, is the answer "no way"?

Comment: In the context of your problem,because the method `SetResult` is called before we call method `Finish();`,so the methods `OnStop` and `OnDestroy`  of  the `activity_list` will been  executed after you `SetResult` to the  page `activity_main`, so is this still necessary if we still  deal with some operations(in this case, pass value to `activity_main`) in method `OnDestroy()`?

Comment: I know what you mean, but before we called `OnDestroy`, the result was passed, so why are we still tangled up in `OnDestroy` handling the pass-value operation?

Comment: I'm not tangled up on OnDestroy. We have already established OnDestroy or OnStop cannot be used. What I'm trying to figure out is whether there's a way, a callback or a override I can use as a centralized "OnClosing" handler.